# Putting two hyperlinks in a google sheets cell

Tags: hyperlink, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 working hyperlinks I want to put in one google sheets cell. I have separated them by '& "." &" and the link names show up in the cell but the links are not hot - clicking them does nothing.

The formula -
HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/166mfynUK7RKOv_biNz6nlenohBIANUEu01DTOaT6Jso/edit#gid=359776838&range=A45","Lftv") & ", " & HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/166mfynUK7RKOv_biNz6nlenohBIANUEu01DTOaT6Jso/edit#gid=359776838&range=A127","Tmro")

I tested both links separately. Both work. I tried varying the number of spaces around the ",&" stuff. No change. I tried upper and lower case 'Hyperlink" syntax. No change. I asked CoPilot. No luck. I looked at prior questions and found this -

```
function addMultipleUrlsToCell() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  sh.getRange('A1').setValue('');
  var RichTextValue=SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
  .setText("Google,GASReference,SO")
  .setLinkUrl(0,6,"https://google.com/")
  .setLinkUrl(7,19,"https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app/")
  .setLinkUrl(20,22,"https://stackoverflow.com")
  .build();
  sh.getRange("A1").setRichTextValue(RichTextValue);
}

function retrieveMultipleUrls() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const rg=sh.getRange(1,1);
  var rtv=rg.getRichTextValue().getRuns();
  var res=rtv.reduce(function(ar,e){
    var url=e.getLinkUrl();
    if(url)ar.push(url);
    return ar;
  },[]);
  console.log(res);
}
```

`
I would like have my simple approach reviewed please before diverging to this. Also, it many not matter but my links are intra-sheet only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you found is a workaround using Google Apps Script. It uses the `RichTextValue` object to create multiple hyperlinks in a single cell. Here's a brief explanation of the code:

- `addMultipleUrlsToCell()`: This function creates a `RichTextValue` object with multiple hyperlinks and sets it to a cell. It first clears the cell A1 in 'Sheet2'. Then it creates a `RichTextValue` object with the text "Google,GASReference,SO" and sets three different hyperlinks for each part of the text. Finally, it sets this `RichTextValue` object to the cell A1.
- retrieveMultipleUrls(): This function retrieves all the hyperlinks from the `RichTextValue` object in a cell. It gets the `RichTextValue` object from the cell A1 in 'Sheet2' and retrieves all the hyperlinks from it. It then logs all the hyperlinks to the console.

If you want to stick with your simple approach, you might need to use separate cells for each hyperlink. If you're okay with using Google Apps Script, the code you found is a good solution. You just need to replace the URLs and the text in the `addMultipleUrlsToCell()` function with your own. Please note that this approach will make the cell's content uneditable from the Sheets UI, as any changes made directly in the cell will remove the hyperlinks. Changes would have to be made via the script.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that if I have to.  I got my approach from CoPilot. which said *START* Using the HYPERLINK() function: This method allows you to create multiple links using a formula. You can use the following syntax:
=HYPERLINK("url1", "link text1") & ", " & HYPERLINK("url2", "link text2") & ", " & ...

For example, if you want to create three links in cell A1, you can use this formula:

=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com", "Google") & ", " & HYPERLINK("https://www.bing.com", "Bing") & ", " & HYPERLINK("https://www.yahoo.com", "Yahoo") ---. *END* It almost works. The link text is there

Comment: That response from me was a little light. Thanks for taking time to explain the code.  I will use it if the simpler route fails.

Comment: I tested the code you explained and it worked great. Simpler than it appeared. Much appreciated.